# Add Printer requires UAC to admin

Tags: printer, active-directory, group-policy, network-printer, lpr

I have several non-admin users on my Active Directory domain that need to be able to add printers without an admin entering their credentials at a UAC prompt.

How do I use group policies to allow non-admin users to install new TCP/IP network printers in Windows without needing elevation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option to disable the credential prompt using Local GPO.

```
Configuration-> Administrative Templates-> Printers. In right pane, double-click  the "Point and Print Restrictions"
```

In the popup window, select "Enabled", then in "Options" select "When installing drivers for a new connection:" to "Do not show warning or elevation prompt " and the "When updating drivers for existing connection:" also to " Do not show warning or elevation prompt ":

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already set, with no effect.